# Vector Field Generating Variation Along Curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

I'm learning a proof of the fact that length extremising curves are geodesics of the Levi-Civita connection, and have found something I don't understand. The argument states the following.

Suppose $\gamma$ is an arbitrary curve in a manifold $M$ and $N$ is an **arbitrary** vector field along $\gamma$ which vanishes at the endpoints. Then there must exist a variation $\tilde{\gamma}$ of $\gamma$ such that $\gamma'$ and $N$ are the pushforwards of the coordinate vector fields on the domain of the variation.

I can't see how this is true, because it would immediately imply that all vector fields commute (I think!). Am I missing something or is it false? If it's wrong, does anyone know how to prove that statement that length extremizing implies geodesic.

The relevant lectures notes from which I've taken this argument are [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~md384/neessnmeiwseis.pdf), page 32. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is only that if you're given a vector field $N$ *along the curve*, then you can find a variation of the curve such that the pushforwards of the coordinate vector fields restrict to $\gamma'$ and $N$ along the curve.  This is not the same as being given a vector field *on the manifold*.

If the dimension of $M$ is 2, and the variation $\tilde\gamma$ happens to be a smooth embedding, then the pushforwards actually will define vector fields on $M$ in a neighborhood of the curve (minus the endpoints), and these vector fields will commute.  The fact that you can do this for an arbitrary $N$ is no contradiction, because in this case $N$ must be nowhere tangent to the curve, and the values of the bracket along the curve are not determined solely by the values of $N$ and $\gamma'$ there; they depend on how the vector fields are extended, because the coordinate formula for the bracket involves differentiating the coefficients of $\gamma'$ in the direction of $N$.

In the example @Ted Shifrin gave with $N=fT$, the above argument doesn't apply, because if $\gamma'$ and $N$ are linearly dependent, then $\tilde \gamma$  *cannot* be an embedding.  And in dimensions higher than 2, you won't ever get vector fields defined on an open subset of $M$; they'll only be defined on the (at most) 2-dimensional image of $\tilde \gamma$.

Comment: I don't quite get your argument. Indeed the commutator of $N$ and $\gamma'$ is precisely the Lie derivative of $N$ with respect to $\gamma'$ which depends only on the value $N$ along $\gamma$. So I don't see how the extension of $N$ has anything to do with the Lie bracket!

Comment: Surprisingly, for vector fields $X$ and $Y$, the Lie derivative $\mathcal L_X Y$ generally doesn't depend only on the values of $X$ and $Y$ along an integral curve of $X$.  For example, consider the following vector fields on the plane: $X_1 = \partial/\partial x$, $X_2 = (1+y)\partial/\partial x$, and $Y = \partial/\partial y$.  Then the $x$-axis is an integral curve of both $X_1$ and $X_2$, and $X_1=X_2$ there; but $\mathcal L_{X_1}Y\ne \mathcal L_{X_2}Y$ along the $x$-axis.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that my last comment isn't quite to the point, because your claim was that the value of the Lie derivative $\mathcal L_X Y$ along an integral curve of $X$ depends only on the values of $Y$ along the curve.  This is in fact true; however, as my example illustrates, it *does* depend on how the vector field $X$ is extended off the curve.  So in the situation you originally asked about, the Lie derivative $\mathcal L_{\gamma'} N$ depends critically on how the vector field $\gamma'$ is extended off the original curve.

Comment: thanks I clearly see that's true now. However intuitively I don't understand why! The Lie derivative $L_X Y$ at $p$ is defined as the rate of change of the pullback of $Y$ along the integral curve of $X$ starting at $p$. Is it because the pullback operation depends on the extension of $X$ around this integral curve? In fact that does seem very plausible to me. I'd be very grateful if you could confirm this, then I'll certainly accept your answer! Cheers!

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.  For example, nearby integral curves of $X$ could spread out, causing the the pullback of $Y$ to get bigger; or they could converge, causing the pullback of $Y$ to get smaller.  There's no way to tell just by looking at values of $X$ along one curve.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your point in the third paragraph: No, it only implies that vector fields that are push-forwards of (constant multiples of) coordinate vector fields commute. True enough, *two* linearly independent vector fields can, in appropriate coordinates, be coordinate vector fields *if* (and only if) their Lie bracket vanishes.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are saying. He seems to be claiming that an arbitrary vector field $N$ along $\gamma$ is automatically a pushforward of a coordinate vector field. This is what I don't believe. Since by what you say that would imply that every vector field along $\gamma$ commutes with the tangent vector field...

Comment: Yes, unless he assumes something more about $N$ ... at least that it's normal, this is hopeless, because if $N=fT$ for a function $f$ that's nonconstant along the curve, $[N,T]=[fT,T]=-T(f)T\ne 0$. ... This is not the proof I would normally give, but I'm a differential forms person.

Comment: Well - he's at least assuming that it is linearly independent I guess, but that doesn't seem strong enough to me. Have you got a reference for a differential forms based proof?

Comment: I would suggest you look at some standard Riemannian geometry texts. Certainly Spivak, doCarmo, etc., get this right. For a differential forms approach, there's O'Neill and Chern-Chen-Lam. I confess I have never scoped out texts for this. If necessary, I'll write something up for you if you're used to the moving frames approach.